# Biopython using re.search() to sort genomic tRNA sequences

Tags: python, biopython

Using Biopython to import fasta formatted genomic sequences for tRNAs, I was writing this search script; when I search for 'AT', in a file downloaded here: http://gtrnadb.ucsc.edu/Hsapi19/hg19-tRNAs.fa; 622 of the 626 results are returned. Of the 4 that I would want to exclude for this search, the 'AT' sequence does actually exist in tRNA 54 (shown below). Why would re.search() not have included this result with the 622? I am not sure if I misused re.search() or if the string is too long?
'AT' can occur anything in the string in that order as described here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    import sys                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    import os                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    import time                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    import re                                                                                                                                                                                                                            


    from Bio import SeqIO                                                                                                                                                                                                                

    filename = 'hg19-tRNAs270.fa'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    search_seq = sys.argv[1]                                                                                                                                                                                                             

    count = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    fails = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    finds = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

    output_handle = open("output_%s.fasta" % search_seq, "w")                                                                                                                                                                            

    for record in SeqIO.parse(filename, "fasta"):                                                                                                                                                                                        
        count += 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

        # print("Record " + record.id + ", length " + str(len(record.seq)))                                                                                                                                                              
        # print record                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        # print 'ID:',record.id                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        # print 'SEQ:',record.seq                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        # print 'DESC:',record.description                                                                                                                                                                                               
        # print 'LENGTH:',str(len(record.seq))                                                                                                                                                                                           

        str_record = record.format("fasta")                                                                                                                                                                                              
        result = re.search(search_seq,str_record)                                                                                                                                                                                        


        if result != None:                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            finds +=1                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            SeqIO.write(record, output_handle, "fasta")                                                                                                                                                                                  
        else:                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            print 'ID:',record.id                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            print 'SEQ:',record.seq                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            print 'DESC:',record.description                                                                                                                                                                                             
            print 'LENGTH:',str(len(record.seq))                                                                                                                                                                                         


    output_handle.close()                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    print("There were " + str(count) + " records in file " + filename)                                                                                                                                                                   
    print("There were " + str(finds) + " matches in the file " + filename + " for sequence: " + (search_seq))
```

-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/Dropbox/shared/" -*-
Compilation started at Fri Jul 11 15:35:06

./fasta_search.py AT
ID: complimentry_to_oligo_probe
SEQ:
DESC: complimentry_to_oligo_probe TCAGTTGGTAGAGCGGAGGA
LENGTH: 0
ID: Homo_sapiens_chr1.trna25-AsnGTT
SEQ: GTCTCTGTGGCGTAGTCGGTTAGCGCGTTCGGCTGTTAACCGAAAAGTTGGTGGTTCGAGCCCACCCAGGAACG
DESC: Homo_sapiens_chr1.trna25-AsnGTT (148000805-148000878)  Asn (GTT) 74 bp  Sc: 72.61
LENGTH: 74
ID: Homo_sapiens_chr19.trna12-GlnTTG
SEQ: AGCAGTGTAGCCTAGTGGCTAGGTCCTCTGACTTTGAAACCACGTGGTCTGGGTTTAAGTCTCAGCTGTGCTA
DESC: Homo_sapiens_chr19.trna12-GlnTTG (9150428-9150356)  Gln (TTG) 73 bp  Sc: 23.15
LENGTH: 73
ID: Homo_sapiens_chr6.trna54-ThrCGT
SEQ: GGCCCTGTAGCTCAGCGGTTGGAGCGCTGGTCTCGTAAACCTAGGGGTCGTGAGTTCAA*AT*CTCACCAGGGCCT
DESC: Homo_sapiens_chr6.trna54-ThrCGT (27586135-27586208)  Thr (CGT) 74 bp  Sc: 63.29
LENGTH: 74
There were 626 records in file hg19-tRNAs270.fa
There were 622 matches in the file hg19-tRNAs270.fa for sequence: AT

Compilation finished at Fri Jul 11 15:35:06

Comment: Weird, if I copy your human sequence and match it in the REPL it does match. Could you print the ```str_record``` for it?

Comment: >Homo_sapiens_chr6.trna25-AlaAGC (26751918-26751990) Ala (AGC) 73 bp Sc: 46.89
GGGGGATTAGCTCAAGCGGTAGGGTGCCTGCTTAGCATGCAAGAGGTAGCAGGATCGACG
CCTGCATTCTCCA

Comment: Still matches. I would suggest using one of the solutions posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably line breaks. FASTA records are usually limited to 60 characters per line (or so the web tells me) so if the format call turned the matching portion into `A\nT` it won't match your regexp. Use `str_record = str(record.seq)` instead (assuming you really want to search only the sequence).

Comment: I was originally trying to do re.search(search_seq,record.seq), got a TypeError, tried str(record) - still a TypeError; however, str(record.seq) for which the type is <class 'Bio.Seq.Seq'> converts to a string! @PeterDeGlopper

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
result = re.search(search_seq,str_record)
```

to

```
result = re.search(search_seq,str_record, re.MULTILINE)
```

My guess is that record.format() adds a newline to your str_record string.